# Brain transplant or ....body transplant?

Tags: brain

From a surgery point of view, which option is easier, requiring less skills thus having minor chances of failure in the hand of skilled surgeons?

-Transplanting a new brain in another body

-Replacing pieces of the old body around the brain over the course of years

My intuition tells me that the first method has high chances of critical failure for the brain to die of asphyxiation, the second option might seem more reasonable, but now the chance of critical failure is small but repeats itself every day over a few years. So it's kind of like 80% chance to die now versus 0.8% chances to die every day for the next 5 years....just throwing completely random numbers around to show what my intuition suggests.

Comment: If it can be done, then replacing the whole body at once would be ideal.

Unfortunately, with our current level of medical and bio knowledge, we can do neither.

We simply do not have a means of connecting the nervous system of the recipient body to the brain.

Comment: @PcMan assuming we have the skills to connect nerves, which ones is actually safest for the brain? which one has lesser chances of dying?

Comment: Head transplant, was in the news someyears ago, how did it ended?

Comment: @MolbOrg with a living head, on a quadruplegic body on life support, and being fed continuous anti0rejection drugs. Just use a clone for the body, it solves the rejection issues. but... we have very limited success even reconnecting single nerves in the extremities. something on the magnitude of connecting a brain to a spinal cord, or connecting a spinal cord to the multitude of nerves in the body? We are very far from that. It's not impossible, just well outside current medical ability

Comment: The second method is widespread nowadays. My father got a transplant kidney and a stent in the aorta, he is fine. Brain transplants OTOH are the stuff of science fiction.

Comment: @PcMan done a litle bit of googling, seems not done yet. Look up for HEAVEN/GEMINI and Canavero. Also it looks like our perceptin on reconnecting neurons are outdated, looking at google results rigth now, seems there are some successes in that direction.

Comment: no matter how you do the second method sooner or later you need to put the brain in a new skull, then it is just the first method with a lot of extra steps

Comment: @The Square-Cube Law  So " Brain transplants OTOH are the stuff of science fiction".  Hmmm. What genre of fiction is Belle asking about writing?  Science fiction.

Comment: @MolbOrg As far as I know, the surgery hasn't been attempted.  Lots of political, ethical, and practical reasons.  Robert A. Heinlein wrote a novel about brain transplant published 1970, and one of the *X Files* movies (second one?) had the villains working on stealing a body for head transplant, interrupted at the point of connected blood supply, severed recipient head, but donor still alive...

Comment: @ZeissIkon Professor Dowell's Head, 1925 - yes, it is an old idea. Will see if it haplens one day, nothing magical about it, just proper tools and ways are required.

Comment: @MolbOrg Exactly.  The key technique is getting the spinal cords to fuse in a functional condition.  Demonstrate that repeatedly on monkeys with 90% or greater function within a few weeks or not much longer (medically induced coma prevents the impatience of the patient causing problems -- but trades them off for others) and figure out the ethics of donor selection and you're there.  Ethics may be a bigger issue than technology...

Comment: @ZeissIkon yep, ethics problem is quite strong here, and without easy cheats on horison. Organ growing and cloning could be a bliss here, eleminating dobius activity in that sector(maybe). Solutions are possibe but it all hefty deal of resources to use to make it happen. We need to push tech to get qualitative change and attack that biology problem, as we quite qualified to do so, technology wise.

Comment: @MolbOrg cloning a body for transplant has its own thorny ethical questions, much like those attached to abortion.  Not to mention that cloning sheep to be born as lambs isn't at all the same as producing an adult body for transplant in less than 18-20 years.

Comment: @ZeissIkon meant cloning cells in the first place, and using it to grow/make organs. Cloning bodies not necessarly fast or convinient and probably a waste of resources(and yes that problem of growth u mentiont). I reffered to existing attempts like 3d print tissues with stem cells. Success is quite limited, last time I saw it, and it may or may not the way to do it as more mature technology. Maybe there are better ways but hardly there is a way around cells cloning like processes in converting small sample of tissue in to kg's of cells. (There are possibilities, like grow it in the body of P)

Comment: In the body of patient, really there is no need for cloned bodies. But it requires better tech.

Comment: For those talking about the difficulty of reconnecting the nerves in the spinal column, it sounds like you're all imagining splicing individual strands & having to get all the right ones connected to the right ones like a telephone technician wiring up a junction box, much more likely it's going to end up being just pasting the two ends together with stem cell injection treatments to promote new growth to join them up & brain plasticity will work it out from there with a long period of physical therapy, much like a new baby learning to walk etc.

Comment: Continued ^  personally I wouldn't expect full functionality in the new body in anything under 24 months, also, you might actually leave the donor bodies brain stem in (to govern automatic heartbeat & breathing etc) and graft the patients brain (sans its brainstem) on top of that so that you don't have to worry about life-support machinery to keep it alive until the new connections have been made.

Comment: Continued again ^ also worth noting a brain transplant patient would experience total sensory deprivation until the new brain & nerve tissue grows & begins to connect up the graft points so probably best to keep them sedated or in an induced coma during that time, at the very least a month, maybe four, maybe more.

Comment: How are you getting around tissue rejection issues? is the new body a cloned one or something?

Answer (score 1):

First method is order of magnitude more complex, but it is better

Until nanomachines, which maybe an order of magnitude harder than even first method, u can't avoid scar tissues, and it won't be good especially when it all over the body parts.

So considering the amount of work and internal connections required, of allsorts of tissues and vessels, second method may be on pair with complexity of a first one (if by brain transplant we loosley mean head transplant as well)

Difficulties of second method are in finding apropriate parts, which won't be easy, they do have to not reject themselfs. But as a solution is potencial stemcells 3d printing of new organs, or other ways artificially to grow them. I seems have seen some results on both of those(3d printing, and growing - small pieces very limited) but if we talk about random parts and organs, all of them, it seems to be even harder than head transplant.

So on a scale which you would like it to see, replacing all, I would say that head transplant is closer to reality as for today.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_transplant

https://www.google.com/search?q=HEAVEN/GEMINI

Topic is quite old, even its recent development, some sucesses are reported(on animals), but not sure about results with this guy https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergio_Canavero he prepares for that for a decade already

So if your villan needs a transplant near 2023 go with a head one.

If it is nanomachines son time, then go with brain transplant and freshly cloned/printed body as one of the options, never trust those digital uploaders, go with good old stuff.

Comment: I would argue that if scarring is the issue, the consequences of inevitable scar points in a brain transplant are far worse, even if they are physically more diminuitive than overall body scarring from progressive replacement of body parts.

Comment: @DKNguyen do not cut brain pieces obiviously, it should be one piece transplant, and then why so? I mean u may not argue, but at least some hints of why

Comment: You don't cut up the brain into pieces in a brain transplant anymore than you cut the heart up into pieces in a heart transplant. Have you ever had a nerve cut or even a bruised nerve? I have. Twice. They actually try to go around it during jaw surgery. It basically never heals. It sucks. It's like trying to use your foot when it falls asleep for a long time. And in a brain transplant you will purposefully be cutting nerves, all the nerves, to remove the brain.

Comment: @DKNguyen as I mention by brain transplant, if nothing better, I mean head transplant. Also I mention 2 situations are complex enough. While googling I have seen some works on grow of connections of nerve tissues, there is some progress, compared to 10-20 years ago. My main point rather was - organ transplantation on scale of piecewise rebuild a body isn't easier. The problem mentiont by u exists for all parts and organs of the human body(more or less). Yes restoring spinal cord connectivity is a big obstacle, everyone sees that, ignoring less obivious problems.

Comment: @DKNguyen *"It basically never heals"* not always 100% true, I had that with my left big toe, fell asleep in a trench on exercise with my foot wedged hard against its wall & that toe pressed up hard against the inside of my boot, that toe was permanently numb after that, I thought the nerve would never recover but it did, it probably took ten years for full recovery of sensation in that toe mind.

Comment: @Pelinore That doesn't sound like it was severed though which was the specific type of trauma I had in mind. I'm more amazed that it fell asleep for that long to be honest than the fact it healed. Did it die from lack of blood flow?

Comment: @DKNguyen did the nerve die from lack of blood flow? couldn't say, I believe I got about four or five hours kip that night & the foot was wedged hard against the wall & the whole foot numb when I woke, how much of the time I was asleep it was like that I couldn't say, but there wasn't any noticeable bruising or necrosis to the toe or foot the following few days so blood flow doesn't seem to have been the issue.

Comment: @DKNguyen If you want sliced though there's the tip of my finger I sliced off along one side of the tip (maybe a millimetre thick sliver five millimetres long & a few wide), was still connected by a thin bit at the side so I just flapped it back down & taped it in place, healed up nicely, that severed enough for you ;) for a long time the surface sensation from that bit of skin was off (four or five years at a guess) but I seem to have got full sensation back on that as well, that one was picking up a broken glass while a little drunk.

Comment: @Pelinore Maybe you're the Man From Earth.

Comment: @DKNguyen nah, just not all nerves are equal & not all nerve damage is either would be my guess, but I do remember seeing a report some few years back that said contrary to what had previously been thought some nerves can 'sometimes' grow back / repair themselves under certain conditions, but very slowly.

Comment: @Pelinore I wish they would grow back in my face and those weren't even severed. Just bruised I'm told.

Comment: @DKNguyen Oh! sorry to hear that :( if the broken or dead bit is only a small bit so that the distance between healthy nerve at each side of the dead or broken bit is very short & they're still pointed at each other (so new growth will only bridge a small gap maybe?) iirc then some recovery of nerve function has been recorded iirc but it takes rather a long time compared to normal healing & isn't always a perfect repair job, which ties in with my own experience (I went looking because I suddenly realised I had recovered some sensation is how I came across the report but I never kept a link).